# Python logic behind negating a if statement with the and operator in

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, nested, logic

I got the following code where I am stuck in the reasoning behind the nested logic:

```
if not ((0 <= x <=3) and (0 <= y <= 3)):
    print('A')
elif y < 1 or y > 2:
    print('B')
elif x < 1 or x > 2:
    print('C')
else:
    print('D')
```

I am trying to determine what values will get the string "D" printed but I am not getting through the first if statement. I understand that the negation of (0 <= x <= 3) is (0 > x > 3) but how do I continue to evaluate the statement with the and operator? Does that mean that no one of the x and y intervals should be true? I'm really stuck here.

Comment: The first conditional: (0 <= x <=3) and (0 <= y <= 3) is a square box with left lower vertex at the origin with width and height 3.  We print 'A' for anything outside this square box.

Comment: *I understand that the negation of (0 <= x <= 3) is (0 > x > 3)* – no, the negation of `0 <= x <= 3` is `x < 0 or x > 3`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for pointing this out! That means that the negation of a "double inequality" where the original has the AND operator in between switches to the OR operator! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to determine what values will get the string `"D"`

```
x, y = 2, 2

if not ((0 <= x <=3) and (0 <= y <= 3)):
    print('A')
elif y < 1 or y > 2:
    print('B')
elif x < 1 or x > 2:
    print('C')
else:
    print('D')
```

The output:

```
D
```

---

If you don't want to proceed with negation like `if not (<cond1> and <cond2>):` - you need to decompose the conditions in different and more *manageable* way.

Comment: Alright I see. But if I deconstruct it to: (0 <= x and x <= 3 and 0 <= y and x <= y) is the negation then the opposite of every condition in the parentheses?

Comment: @MaxPower, from your previous comment: why this `0 <= y and x <= y` should be equivalent to `(0 <= y <= 3)`? or was that just a typo?

Comment: Yeah there is a typo, here is what I meant:
0 <= x and x <= 3 and 0 <= y and y <= 3

Answer (score 0):

Your riddle only uses numbers from 0 to 3 to test - you can easily check the numbers -1 to 4 to see what output is given and "reverse engeneer" your logic - by  "testing" your way trough your conditions:

```
for x in range(-1,5):
    for y in range(-1,5):
        print(x,y,end=" -> ")
        if not ((0 <= x <=3) and (0 <= y <= 3)):
            print('A')
        elif y < 1 or y > 2:
            print('B')
        elif x < 1 or x > 2:
            print('C')
        else:
            print('D',x,y)
```

Output:

```
-1 -1 -> A
-1 0 -> A
-1 1 -> A
-1 2 -> A
-1 3 -> A
-1 4 -> A
0 -1 -> A
0 0 -> B
0 1 -> C
0 2 -> C
0 3 -> B
0 4 -> A
1 -1 -> A
1 0 -> B
1 1 -> D 1 1     # here
1 2 -> D 1 2     # here
1 3 -> B
1 4 -> A
2 -1 -> A
2 0 -> B
2 1 -> D 2 1     # here
2 2 -> D 2 2     # here
2 3 -> B
2 4 -> A
3 -1 -> A
3 0 -> B
3 1 -> C
3 2 -> C
3 3 -> B
3 4 -> A
4 -1 -> A
4 0 -> A
4 1 -> A
4 2 -> A
4 3 -> A
4 4 -> A
```

Comment: Nice trick! The thing is just that this is a question from a pre-test and we will not have any tools accept a pen and paper to determine our answers :/

Comment: @MaxPower Actually this is far easier to understand with pen and paper than with code. Draw some vertical lines representing the boundaries for x and some horizontal lines representing the boundaries for y and see which area is represented by which `if` case.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement might be easier to understand if you write it [equivalently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) as:

```
if (not 0 <= x <= 3) or (not 0 <= y <= 3):
   ...
```

Your code will move past it if and only if `0 <= x <= 3 and 0 <= y <= 3`.

Your code will move past the two `elif` if and only if `1 <= y <= 2` and `1 <= x <= 2`.

Thus your code will print `D` if and only if `0 <= x <= 3 and 0 <= y <= 3 and 1 <= y <= 2 and 1 <= x <= 2`. There is redundancy in that logical statement; it is equivalent to: `1 <= x <= 2 and 1 <= y <= 2`.